# Python 3 and bisection functions to check size of a font

Tags: python, algorithm, fonts

I have the following function to check whether a `font size` is small enough to fit into an `image` of dimensions `x`, `y`.

```
from PIL import ImageFont                                                       

def fit(width, height, font, size, text):                                       
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font, size)                                       
    text_w, text_h = font.getsize(text)                                         
    text_area = text_w*text_h                                                   
    total_area = width*height                                                   
    if total_area>text_area:                                                    
        return True                                                             
    else:                                                                       
        return False                                                            



font = 'font.ttf'                                                               
counter = 0                                                                     
size = 60                                                                       
text = """                                                                      
The module is called bisect because it uses a basic bisection algorithm to do its w
"""                                                                             
while True:                                                                     
    counter += 1                                                                
    ans = fit(500, 500, font, size, text)                                       
    if ans == True:                                                             
        break                                                                   
    else:                                                                       
        size -=1                                                                
print("Font_Size: {}".format(size))                                             
print("Repetitions: {} ".format(counter))
```

Well, this codes takes as arguments `width` and `height` of an image and calculate the total area and compares with the total area of the text and if it fits (`total area > total area text`) returns true. What I want to do is the following:

I want the biggest `font size` that fits into the area.

We can achieve this with a for-loop, starting out with a high value and subtracting `1` in each iteration. It works but it's slow.

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this with the built-in function for the bisection algorithm that Python implements or do you have guys any other ideas?

The font that I'm using is the following: https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Open+Sans

and the output of the above code is:
`Font_Size: 49
Repetitions: 12`

Comment: The builtin bisect-function is meant for sorted lists, but does not help for saving function calls. You need a custom bisecting function like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given two integers `a<b` and a monotonous function `f` from the integers to booleans (`True,False`), where `f(a) = True` and `f(b) = False` you can find the maximal integer `m` in `[a,b[` with `f(m) = True` with the following function:

```
def findMaxOk(low_ok, high_notOk, f):
  print "find max. ok in [%d,%d[" % (low_ok, high_notOk)
  if low_ok+1 >= high_notOk:
    return low_ok
  mid = (low_ok + high_notOk) // 2
  if f(mid):
    return findMaxOk(mid, high_notOk, f)
  else:
    return findMaxOk(low_ok, mid, f)
```

To find the maximal font size you could then define a function like this:

```
def maxFittingFontSize(width, height, font, text):
  f = lambda size: fit(width, height, font, size, text)
  return findMaxOk(1, 100, f)
```

Btw: Don't you want to compare in your function `fit` width and height separately? like:

```
def fit(width, height, font, size, text):
  font = ImageFont.truetype(font, size)
  text_w, text_h = font.getsize(text)
  return text_w<width and text_h<height
```